# Python 2.7: Using subprocess and a For Loop to output results

Tags: python, linux, for-loop

I have a script that will check multiple hosts for a string pattern (in this case it looks for "Platform." I want to add to this program to make it print something if it cannot find that search pattern. Can someone help guide me in the right direction? For example, if it did not find any "Platform" then it would not print out and it would instead print "We could not find that host!"

#! /usr/bin/python

```
import commands, os, string
import sys
import fileinput
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex


nodename = raw_input("Enter the hostname: ")

hostname=['hostA', 'hostB', 'hostC']

for i in hostname:
    print "Checking Host List..."

    cmd = "ls -l" + hostname
    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    if out.find("Platform") > -1:
        print out
        break
```

Comment: I am not too sure what you want according to the code you posted. You do not actually use the hostnames in your `hostname` list, so why iterating over it ?

Comment: I changed the actual code, because the real code had sensitive information. But i have modified the above script to include hostname variable now

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands, os, string
import sys
import fileinput
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex


nodename = raw_input("Enter the hostname: ")

hostname=['hostA', 'hostB', 'hostC']

for i in hostname:
    print "Checking Host List..."

    cmd = "ls -l "+i
    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print out

    if out.find("Platform") > -1:
        print out
        break

    if i == hostname[-1]:
        print "We could not find that host!"
```

`hostname[-1]` is actually a shortcut for the last element of the `hostname` list. So, you will only enter in that last if block if you reached the last element of the `hostname` list and that it did not contain `"Platform"`.